# F# version of Scala code using zipWithIndex

Tags: scala, f#

This Scala code (somewhat simplified by me, so I might have made a mistake) converts a series of newline separated input lines into a list of coordinates of non-space characters within those lines. Below it is my failed attempt to convert it into F#.

The first coordinate is the index of the character within the line, the second is the coordinate of the line within the string.

F# doesn't seem to have an equivalent of zipWithIndex (though it does have a map overload that provides an index), and the syntax of sequence expressions is quite different to that of Scala's generator expressions, and I am struggling to write the F# equivalent.

The Scala code:

```
val input = "X \n X"

def charCoors(input: String) = for {
    (xs, y) <- input.split('\n').map(_.zipWithIndex).zipWithIndex.iterator
    (c, x) <- xs.iterator
    if c != ' '
  } yield Coord(x, y)
```

My broken F# attempt:

```
let splitLines (s:string) = 
    List.ofSeq(s.Split([|'\n'|]))

let input = "X \n X"

let charCoords input =
    let lines = splitLines input
    seq {
        for (y, line) in List.map (fun y line -> (y, line)) lines do
            yield! for (x, character) in List.map (fun x character -> (x, character)) do
                if char != ' ' then
                    yield (x, y)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you almost had it - you just have to use `List.mapi` and `Seq.mapi` for the line (as a string is `IEnumerable<char>` but not a list):

```
let charCoords input =
    let lines = splitLines input
    seq {
        for (y, line) in List.mapi (fun y line -> (y, line)) lines do
        for (x, character) in Seq.mapi (fun x character -> (x, character)) 
                                       line do
        if character <> ' ' then yield (x, y)
    }
```

Please note that this compiles and runs but I don't know if id does what you want:

```
> charCoords input;;

val it : seq<int * int> = seq [(0, 0); (1, 1)]
```

Comment: thanks! I was confused because the error I got was "This expression was expected to have type 'a -> string * 'a  but here has type 'b * 'c", with reference to "for (y, line)" - and the type inference error made me think my approach was maybe totally wrong somewhere!

Comment: that one came from `.map` vs `.mapi`